# How to find index of an image using its src attribute

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="store04">
<img src="g04/01.jpg" alt="img">
<img src="g04/02.jpg" alt="img">
</div>
```

js

```
$(".btnsI > img").click(function(){
var x = "g04/01.jpg";
var index = $("#store04").find(x).index();
alert (index); // -1
});
```

I need zero as result, because `g04/01.jpg` belongs to image with zero index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".btnsI > img").click(function(){
    var x = "g04/01.jpg";
    var index = $('#store04 [src="'+ x +'"]').index();
    alert (index); // -1
});
```

Note I uses single quotes to allow for doubles on the `[=]` expression (in case the filename contains special characters, which includes the period `.`).

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) for this:

```
$("#store04").find( 'img[src="' + x + '"]' ).index();
```

Comment: This will fail because of the special characters in the filename. Well done on the popularity stakes though :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie thanks for spotting that, I have added double quotes to selector so now should be ok